Вопрос по Google Forms и Discord
Пытаюсь понять как сделать так что бы при заполнение ответов в Гугл форме
в Дс приходил вебхук с аватаркой пользователя.
Знаю что это можно сделать по ID дискорда которой они указывают в ответах.
discordPayload = 
  { 
    content: <@!"+disID+">,
          embeds: 
          [{
            type: 'rich',
            title: ':card_box: :dividers:',
            url:" Тут ссылка ",
            color: 000066,
            fields: [],
            thumbnail: {
            "url": " Картинка "
            },
            image: 
             {
             "url": Avatar // Сюда надо вставить аватарку пользователя 
             },
            footer: {
            text: " По всем вопросам Alkado_o",
            icon_url: "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/ytc/AIdro_nJeSjsN68s9LFlhmNzFEyJQNno1FG5t_OerbiQ_6Mwnqw=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj" // Нижний колонтитул с иконочкой
                }
          }]
  }

Где disID - это ID Discorda
Я уже +- понимаю как это сделать но у меня не выходит из за не хватки знания и банального понимания.

Реализовать можно парсингом гугл формы (видел на гитхабе Google Forms Response Parser, написан на питоне) + парсингом аватарки из дс (могу ошибаться, но вроде discord.py позволяет такое делать)

Решение
function getAvatarUrl(userId) {
  var url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/users/' + userId;
  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': ' Ссыллка '
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var user = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var avatarUrl = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/' + userId + '/' + user.avatar + '.png?size=480';

  return avatarUrl;
}

Где " Ссылка " требуется вставить ссылку авторизации. можно использовать токин авторизации от бота но мы использовали кусок ссылки от авторизации через Web.discird. По факту каждый раз от моего имени делается запрос на получение данных о аватарки пользователя
thumbnail: {
"url": getAvatarUrl(disID)
},
image: 

Чисто как временное решение очень удобно. Если нужно будет помощь с поиском данной ссылки пишите
